# Adding a photo to iPhoto by right clicking in the Finder

Tags: macos, finder, photos.app

How does one add iPhoto to the list of choices when right clicking on a photo in the Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom service for Finder using Automator.app. 
Open **Automator.app** located in /Applications/ folder by default.  When prompted to choose a document type, choose "Service".

[image: Automator Service]

On the top you will see a a box with drop downs.  Select **"image files"** for the drop down box **"Service receives selected"** and choose **"Finder"** for the in.

[image: Service selection]

Then on the left hand side with the **"Actions"** tab selected choose **"Photos"** then drag **"Import Files into iPhoto"** into the workflow area to the right.

[image: Action Selector]

Configure the settings to where the photo will import into iPhoto.  The defaults are Existing album and Events.

Save your workflow and give it a name that will make it obvisous when you choose Services in the Right click menu.  (Ex.  "Import photo to iPhoto")

[image: right click service]

Services you create from Automator are saved in the path: **~/Library/Services/**